Facing errors while loading LLAMA-3 8b 8 bit quantized GGUF model
I am building a document QA system, under which I have a config.yml as below
Config.yml

RETURN_SOURCE_DOCUMENTS: True
VECTOR_COUNT: 2
CHUNK_SIZE: 500
CHUNK_OVERLAP: 50
DATA_PATH: 'data/'
DB_FAISS_PATH: 'vectorstore/db_faiss'
MODEL_TYPE: 'llama'
MODEL_BIN_PATH: 'models\Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct.Q6_K.gguf'
MAX_NEW_TOKENS: 256
TEMPERATURE: 0.0

But when I run the code, I am unable to load the model and getting the below error
ERROR: byte not found in vocab: '
'
CUDA error 9 at D:\a\ctransformers\ctransformers\models\ggml\ggml-cuda.cu:6045: invalid configuration argument
